# SQL Select Puzzle

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok..here's what I want to do.  I've oversimplified the example below:-

I have a table (Table1) with references in like this:

**Table1_ID (PK)**

**Table1_ID Description**

There's another table (Table2):-

**Table2_ID (PK)**

**Table2_LinkedID (FK)**

**Table2_Status <--value is "open" or "complete"**

Table2_LinkedID is linked to Table1_ID.

Ok.  Now I have three queries that I want to connect together.  Here is what I need.

First query:-

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

This works fine.

I want to add two additional columns to the query.  The first is the total number of records in Table2 where the foreign key equals the primary key of table1 (ie SELECT *).

The second will be a count of records where Table2_Status = 'completed'

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.Table1_ID, 
    t1.Table1_Description, 
    t2.TotalCount, 
    t2.CompletedCount
from Table1 t1
left outer join (
    select Table2_LinkedID, 
        count(*) as TotalCount,
        count(case when Table2_Status = 'completed' then 1 end) as CompletedCount
    from Table2
    group by Table2_LinkedID
) t2 on t1.Table1_ID = t2.Table2_LinkedID
```

Comment: Great stuff.  I used this as the basis of my solution and it works perfectly.  Learned something new, too - had never come across the case when syntax before..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE Table2_LinkedID = t1.ID) cntTotal,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE Table2_LinkedID = t1.ID AND Table2_Status = 'completed') cntCompleted
FROM Table1 t1
```

Make sure to have a proper index for the foreign key and for `Table2_Status` for best performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple `GROUP BY` with aggregates:

```
SELECT 
Table1.ID, 
Table1.Description,
Count(Table2.ID) AS TotalT2,
Sum(CASE WHEN Table2.Status = 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfCompleted
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.LinkedID = Table1.ID
GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table1.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

Query 1:

```
select a.ID
        , count(1) as Table2_RecordCount
from Table1 a
inner join Table2 b on b.LinkedID = a.ID
group by a.ID
```

Query 2:

```
select a.ID
        , count(1) as Table2_RecordCount
from Table1 a
inner join Table2 b on b.LinkedID = a.ID
where b.[Status] = 'completed'
group by a.ID
```